# Heroku: Run a function in a certain time

Tags: web-services, node.js, heroku

I'm writing a backend for a mobile application using **Heroku** as my deployment solution and **Node.js** for my platform.

What I simply try to do is to run my function **clearTableX()** to perform at a certain time (lets say 12PM). What function does is that it removes the elements in an entire table.

How would I be able to accomplish that? The one thing that is really important it has to run **one time and one time** only so that it wouldn't delete the same table over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) addon sounds like it will do what you need.

Comment: No problem. Good luck :) But your problem description does sound a bit strange. Obviously I don't know exactly what you need to do, but if you just need a regular job to tidy up some mess caused by a different process then perhaps there's a nicer way to prevent the mess being left around in the first place? Scheduled cleanup jobs give off a bit of 'code smell' to me... ;)